# How can I burn mts files to DVD?

Tags: windows, conversion, dvd, burning, mts

I just bought a new [Canon Vixia HF10](http://www.usa.canon.com/consumer/controller?act=ModelInfoAct&fcategoryid=177&modelid=16186) which saves video file in `.MTS`. Yesterday I had a family party and recorded it. I would like to burn the recorded files to DVD to send my family.

I have tried to burn it with Nero version, but it did not work.

Please let me know which program can burn the MTS files to DVD.
Thanks.

Comment: if you haven't seen them already, check the few questions in the [mts tag](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mts) for suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

The .mts files can be burnt with ImgBurn or Nero, just start a project as a data one. (Simply copy them to the new project and burn them directly like you'd write out some files.)

Or you also want to convert the files so they can be played on a DVD player?

If you want to, then [here](http://www.squidoo.com/mts-files) is an app. As well as [many others](http://www.google.com/search?q=mts+converter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) out there. What output format should you choose? I'd simply go with DivX (since its widely supported on DVD players) if the content and quantity matters, not the quality. If you want better quality, convert them to DVD format. You'll still lose plenty of the quality. (The best way is to "own" a HD media player (which comes with a HDD, hardware HD video decoder, etc) and play it back with that. Or use a computer , connect it to the TV and that's it. (Notice: Playing back HD videos got some requirements, make sure the PC supports the playback.)

Answer (score 1):

The new version of windows live movie maker can convert most video files to dvd format and create menus and so-on. It's free and pretty easy to use. If you're on Windows 7 it should support .mts files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Windows the easiest way is to convert the .MTS files using Handbrake or a simpler Handbrake interface like [Videcoder](http://vidcoder.codeplex.com/) (Vidcoder is much simpler to use).

Once you have the files in .MP4 format you can use DVDFlick to convert and burn the DVD.

As far as I know all of the software is open source and clean.

Answer (score 0):

If:

- all of the MTS files fit onto a single- or dual-layer DVD (4.7 or
  8.5GB respectively), and
- you've saved the entire BDMV folder from the video camera

then with some simple file renames and moves, you can arrange those files into a directory structure that when burned to a DVD is Blu-ray playable (as long as the Blu-ray player can play AVCHD files). Here's instructions I found on the web: http://www.avchduser.com/articles/avchd_to_bluray.jsp